# Cypher - Product not purchased by customer

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using neo4j and have Products , category and sub category. I want to get remaining products which is not yet purchased from sub categories, or we can say product recommendation. I have this query which return those products and sub categories which is purchased by specific customer , I don't know how to inverse it or how to use where not purchased, please help me, thanks much!!!

```
MATCH (n:Customer {customerId : '323'})-[:PURCHASED]->()-[:PRODUCT]->(p:Product)-[:PART_OF_SUBCAT]->(sb:SubCategory) RETURN p,sb
```

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements? Do you want all products from all subcategories that have not been purchased from the customer, or just from the same subcategories that the user has already purchased products from? And do you want just the recommended product returned, or the product and its subcategory?

Comment: @InverseFalcon - I want to return recommended product just from the same subcategories that the user has already purchased products from.Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do it is to collect the products the user has purchased, and match on the products in the same subcategories that aren't in that collection.

```
MATCH (:Customer {customerId : '323'})-[:PURCHASED]->()-[:PRODUCT]->(p:Product)-[:PART_OF_SUBCAT]->(sb:SubCategory) 
WITH COLLECT(p) as boughtProducts, sb
MATCH (recommended:Product)-[:PART_OF_SUBCAT]->(sb)
WHERE NOT recommended IN boughtProducts
RETURN DISTINCT recommended
```

If you are only interested in a certain number of recommended items, you'll want to add a LIMIT clause at the end.